# Multi-column layout

Tags: html, css, grid, multiple-columns, dreamweaver

I am trying to design a multi-column photo gallery on Dreamweaver. The grid looks perfect in the Dreamweaver preview, but as soon as I load it up to the server it's a mess.

This is what I get from the Dreamweaver preview:

[Dreamweaver Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBdxZ.jpg)
[image]

This is what happens once I upload it to the server:

[Server Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJepO.png)
[image]

If you would like to take a look at the server side in more detail please check out www.tinajarrett.com/events.html

Any help or advice would be appreciated since it's driving me mad.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Took a look at website via the link you provided and it seems to be working for me. If it still looks bad on your end I would clear your cache and refresh the page.  Try another browser as well to see if its a browser issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking. I managed to work my way around it using the masonry plugin, so much easier than how I was originally going about it.